# Android - android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Tags: android, networkonmainthread

I have this exception and I was reading a thread on this, and it seemed confusing:

[How to fix android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

I already added this line to my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

On that discussion, they talk about the main execution thread of the app not being able to do networking. What I am wondering is how to restructure my code so that it is inline with Android good practices.

Here is my Activity class for this:

```
package com.problemio;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
public class LoginActivity extends Activity 
{
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

        // Show form for login_email
        final EditText loginEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_email);  
        String name = loginEmail.getText().toString();  

        // Show field for password  
        final EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);  
        String text = password.getText().toString();                  

        // Show button for submit
        Button submit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.submit);   




        // Show options for create-profile and forgot-password




        submit.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() 
        {  
           public void onClick(View v) 
           {
              String email = loginEmail.getText().toString();
              String pass = password.getText().toString(); 
              sendFeedback(pass, email);
            }
        });        
    }


    public void sendFeedback(String pass , String email) 
    {  
        Log.d( "1" , pass );
        Log.d( "1" , email );

        // Go to db and check if these r legit
        // How do I do that? :)
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();  
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", email ));  
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", pass ));

        String responseString = null;

        try 
        {  
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("myUrl");

            // no idea what this does :)
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters));

            // This is the line that send the request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();            

            InputStream is = entity.getContent();
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {     
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
        }        
    }          
}
```

What am I doing wrong here and how could I fix it? :) Thanks!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

Comment: Use OkHTTP library: http://square.github.io/okhttp/ or AsyncTask(as others said)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

**NetworkOnMainThreadException:** The exception that is thrown when an application attempts to perform a networking operation on its main thread.

You should call sendfeedback method on asynctask then only above code will work. As webserver is taking lot of time to response main thread becomes unresponsive. To avoid it you should call it on another thread. Hence asynctask is better.

here is [link](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2009/05/painless-threading.html) that illustrates how to use asynctask

Comment: `AsyncTask` is now deprecated, a better alternative is to use `java.util.concurrent.Executors` to execute networking tasks in another thread.

Answer (score 36):

**NetworkOnMainThreadException** is thrown when your app tries networking operation in main thread.

To fix that you can use a private inner class within your Activity that extends `android.os.AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result>` which will do the server call stuffs.

Something as,

```
private class SendfeedbackJob extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String[] params) {
        // do above Server call here
        return "some message";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String message) {
        //process message
    }
}
```

And then invoke above class from `submit.setOnClickListener` as below,

```
SendfeedbackJob job = new SendfeedbackJob();
job.execute(pass, email);
```

[image: AsyncTask]

### References

[AsyncTask doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

[AsyncTask Android example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9671602/432903)

Comment: Come on mate, thats so beautiful :)

Answer (score 14):

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
}
```

Comment: Not really, when you just need a small test and created a fresh small android project just for that.. :)

Comment: Well its a good idea, if you are just testing the app for data manipulation, and don't wanna bother about threads for a while.

Comment: Strictly not recommended, but if you're testing some functionality and need to do it faster you can use it. It's strongly suggested that you shouldn't use this in a production environment. We don't want badly designed apps, do we?

Comment: For more discussion (45 comments!) see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9289190/253938

Answer (score 8):

```
 try 
    {  
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("myUrl");

        // no idea what this does :)
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters));

        // This is the line that send the request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();            

        InputStream is = entity.getContent();
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {     
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
    }
```

Here is your problem. Since api 11, this exception will inform you that you are running long tasks on the ui thread (the http communication in your class), and according with the new StrictGuard policy this is not possibile. So you have two different choice

1. Use thread or aynctask in order to execut yout long term task (better way)

Comment: About changing the `StrictMode.setThreadPolicy` you can read this: http://android-er.blogspot.com/2012/04/strictmodesetthreadpolicy-and.html

Comment: this code does nothing?  How can this be an answer?

Comment: I provided an explanation to the issue. The snippet was meant to point out the ertor , not to solve op's problem. @Cicorias

Comment: I can't up vote now till an edit occurs. I agree now.

Answer (score 3):

You made network call on main thread which is against to android rules, so you have to do your network call on separate thread like asynctask or handler etc.

Answer (score 3):

You can just create Async class as below

```
class Retrievedata extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
         try{
                //Your code 
                }
        return null;
    }
}
```

You can just put your all code inside doInBackground method

Comment: use volley library-Have a look at this -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16836992/how-to-do-a-simple-async-task-using-volley-library-android

Answer (score 1):

Use thread for that case,

```js
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try  {
            //Code here
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});

thread.start();
```

Comment: I like this answer because it uses java code and a Thread.  Why? 1. because all this convert to kotlin stuff sucks.  2. constant deprecations async now concurrent bla bla bla so I'll bet that deprecating Thread will be too hard for google to do.

Answer (score 0):

look at this link : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html

The exception that is thrown when an application attempts to perform a networking operation on its main thread.
Applications targeting earlier SDK versions are allowed to do networking on their main event loop threads, but it's heavily discouraged.

if you set minSdkVersion <11, then your application will work and you can run network operation in main thread.

Answer (score 0):

After a long research (lasted half day) I have found a solution for my problem which is similar to the problem indicated here. The exception displayed by my *Android Studio 2.3.3* was this:

> android studio android.os.networkonmainthreadexception

The problem was based on the impossibility to set a UI variable in the MainActivity. So I saw the following video and I solved my problem. I hope it is also useful to others:

[How to avoid android os NetworkOnMainThreadException](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xXkjfnhqRGI)

Answer (score 0):

As indicated [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask), `AsyncTask` is deprecated, and Google recommends you use the `java.util.concurrent` package or [Kotlin coroutines](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines)

You can execute your network task in another thread very easily using `java.util.concurrent.Executors`.

Simply add these two variables to your `LoginActivity` class:

```
val executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
```

Then surround your networking call with an `executor.execute{}` block:

```
executor.execute {
    /**
     * Executes network task in background. You cannot
     * access view elements here.
     */
    
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();            

    InputStream is = entity.getContent()

}
```