# Connecting to a URL

Tags: android, url

I want to read the content of a URL with the following code :

```
        myUrl=new URL(url);
        stream=myUrl.openStream();
```

but the second line of code triggers an "android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException" without any other explanation.

I work under Androïd 4 and I can add this code used to work with Androïd 2.3.3.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance for the time you will spend trying to help me.

Comment: I think you need to put your code in a separate thread or an AsyncTask.

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9415736) would help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So problem is that application attempts to perform a networking operation on main thread and this is not allowed.

For your goal i recommend to you use `AsyncTask` and do your work in background `Thread`.

Here is example from my little app:

```
protected InputStream doInBackground(String... params) {

            int contentLength = 0;
            int buffLength = 0;
            int progress = 0;
            InputStream inputStream = null;
            try {

                URL url = new URL(params[0]);
                HttpURLConnection urlConntection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConntection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConntection.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
                urlConntection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
                urlConntection.connect();
                if (urlConntection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    contentLength = urlConntection.getContentLength();
                    progressDialog.setMax(contentLength);
                    inputStream = urlConntection.getInputStream();

                    while ((buffLength = inputStream.read(MAX_BUFFER)) != -1) {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(1);
                            progress += buffLength;
                            DataTransmitted data = new DataTransmitted(progress, contentLength);
                            publishProgress(data);
                        }
                        catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                            Log.e(this.getClass().getName(), ex.getMessage());
                        }
                    }

                }
                else {
                    throw new IOException("No response.");
                }

            }
            catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
                Log.e(this.getClass().getName(), ex.getMessage());
            }
            catch (IOException ex) {
                errorDialog.show();
            }
            return inputStream;
        }
```

Or here is similar topic:

- [`Download a file with Android, and showing the progress in a
  ProgressDialog`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog)

Answer (score 1):

From the Android developer's site:

> > A NetworkOnMainThreadException is thrown when an application attempts to perform a networking operation on its main thread.

You need to put your code in a separate thread or an AsyncTask.

Android versions 3.0 and above are **much stricter** about abuse against the UI Thread [Read this article for more details](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/06/app-force-close-honeycomb-ics.html)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use AsyncTask now here's a quick example, i hope that will help you:

```
public class SimpleWebGrab extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    grabURL("http://android.com");
}

public void grabURL(String url) {
    new GrabURL().execute(url);
}

private class GrabURL extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    private final HttpClient Client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    private String Content;
    private String Error = null;
    private ProgressDialog Dialog = new ProgressDialog(SimpleWebGrab.this);

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Dialog.setMessage("Downloading source..");
        Dialog.show();
    }

    protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            Content = Client.execute(httpget, responseHandler);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            Error = e.getMessage();
            cancel(true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Error = e.getMessage();
            cancel(true);
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
        Dialog.dismiss();
        if (Error != null) {
            Toast.makeText(SimpleWebGrab.this, Error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(SimpleWebGrab.this, "Source: " + Content, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

}
}
```

And please : call it Android, not Androïd it sounds french.