# Using AsyncTask to Send Android Email

Tags: android, debugging, email, asynchronous, task

I had recently asked a question regarding the following code:

[Sending Email in Android using JavaMail API without using the default/built-in app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a)

I had asked this in regards to a network error, as per a previous question:

[Need Help Debugging Email Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14373468/need-help-debugging-email-code)

My question is, how would I implement an AsyncTask in order to successfully send an email with this Android code?  Every tutorial that I see informs me that I should do

```
extend AsyncTask {
```

However, GMailSender.java already has this defined as:

```
public class GMailSender extends javax.mail.Authenticator
```

Would anyone be able to help me?  Thanks!

NOTE:

Please don't be like the idiot who had -1<sup>ed</sup> this question and posted the exact answer as was given in [Sending Email in Android using JavaMail API without using the default/built-in app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a).  I am unable to use that exact coding, due to the fact that it is no longer possible to run a network operation on the main thread of an Android application.  I am looking for a way to use AsyncTask in order to run the operation in the background.  What I am unable to find out is how to do

```
extend AsyncTask {
```

without touching

```
public class GMailSender extends javax.mail.Authenticator
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a pretty good example right on the [`AsyncTask` doc page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Pass your `GMailSender` object in to an `AsyncTask`, and call `GMailSender#sendMail` during `doInBackground`.

That is,

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    final GMailSender sender = new GMailSender("username@gmail.com", "password");
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        @Override public Void doInBackground(Void... arg) {
            try {   
                sender.sendMail("This is Subject",   
                    "This is Body",   
                    "user@gmail.com",   
                    "user@yahoo.com");   
            } catch (Exception e) {   
                Log.e("SendMail", e.getMessage(), e);   
            } 
        }
    }.execute();

}
```

Comment: `doInBackground(Void... arg)` gives me an error of `This method must return a result of type Void`

Comment: Also, I can't do `return null;`, because that would just give me another `null` log.

Comment: Actually, I take it back. I edited the code slightly, and now have it working. Thanks a lot! Cheers!

Comment: Let me know what parts didn't work - I'd be happy to edit the answer for posterity. As a side note, the return value from `doInBackground` is just what gets passed to `onPostExecute`. It's only used if you override that method.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void onClick(View v) {
final GMailSender sender = new GMailSender("username@gmail.com",       "password");
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
    @Override public Void doInBackground(Void... arg) {
        try {   
            sender.sendMail("This is Subject",   
                "This is Body",   
                "user@gmail.com",   
                "user@yahoo.com");   
        } catch (Exception e) {   
            Log.e("SendMail", e.getMessage(), e);   
        } 
    return null;}
}.execute();

}
```

Thank you "dokkaebi"