# sending email on android using smtp and Gmail how to make it work

Tags: android, email, error-handling, smtp, gmail

i am creating android application that send email in background without user interaction i had downloaded the three .jar files as the examples said and added to the manifest file the permission of INTERNET .

but the system display errors can anyone help me to fix this errors

its my first time dealing with email application

## logcat

```
01-13 23:05:20.028: E/MailApp(4357): Could not send email
01-13 23:05:20.028: E/MailApp(4357): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
01-13 23:05:20.028: E/MailApp(4357):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1133)
01-13 23:05:20.028: E/MailApp(4357):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
01-13 23:05:20.028: E/MailApp(4357):    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:365)
01-13 23:05:20.028: E/MailApp(4357):    at javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress.getLocalAddress(InternetAddress.java:517)
01-13 23:05:20.028: E/MailApp(4357):    at javax.mail.internet.UniqueValue.getUniqueMessageIDValue(UniqueValue.java:99)
01-13 23:05:20.028: E/MailApp(4357):    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.updateMessageID(MimeMessage.java:2054)
01-13 23:05:20.028: E/MailApp(4357):    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.updateHeaders(MimeMessage.java:2076)
01-13 23:05:20.028: E/MailApp(4357):    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.saveChanges(MimeMessage.java:2042)
01-13 23:05:20.028: E/MailApp(4357):    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:117)
01-13 23:05:20.028: E/MailApp(4357):    at com.devleb.emaildemoinbackground.GMailSender.send(GMailSender.java:105)
01-13 23:05:20.028: E/MailApp(4357):    at com.devleb.emaildemoinbackground.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:36)
01-13 23:05:20.028: E/MailApp(4357):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
01-13 23:05:20.028: E/MailApp(4357):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
01-13 23:05:20.028: E/MailApp(4357):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
01-13 23:05:20.028: E/MailApp(4357):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-13 23:05:20.028: E/MailApp(4357):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-13 23:05:20.028: E/MailApp(4357):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
01-13 23:05:20.028: E/MailApp(4357):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-13 23:05:20.028: E/MailApp(4357):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-13 23:05:20.028: E/MailApp(4357):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
01-13 23:05:20.028: E/MailApp(4357):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-13 23:05:20.028: E/MailApp(4357):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

## MainActivity.java

```
package com.devleb.emaildemoinbackground;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

     @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            Button addImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
            addImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view) {


                    GMailSender mailsender = new GMailSender("sender@gmail.com", ".........");

                    String[] toArr = { "receiver@gmail.com"};
                    mailsender.set_to(toArr);
                    mailsender.set_from("sender@gmail.com");
                    mailsender.set_subject("This is an email sent using my Mail JavaMail wrapper from an Android device.");
                    mailsender.setBody("Email body.");

                    try {
                        //mailsender.addAttachment("/sdcard/filelocation");

                        if (mailsender.send()) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                    "Email was sent successfully.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Email was not sent.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {

                        Log.e("MailApp", "Could not send email", e);
                    }
                }
            });

        }
    }
```

## GmailSender.java

```
package com.devleb.emaildemoinbackground;



import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.activation.CommandMap;
import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.activation.DataSource;
import javax.activation.FileDataSource;
import javax.activation.MailcapCommandMap;
import javax.mail.BodyPart;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;

public class GMailSender extends javax.mail.Authenticator {
    private String _user;
      private String _pass;

      private String[] _to;
      private String _from;

      private String _port;
      private String _sport;

      private String _host;

      private String _subject;
      private String _body;

      private boolean _auth;

      private boolean _debuggable;

      private Multipart _multipart;


      public GMailSender() {
        _host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // default smtp server
        _port = "465"; // default smtp port
        _sport = "465"; // default socketfactory port

        _user = "sender@gmail.com"; // username
        _pass = "..........."; // password
        _from = "receive@gmail.com"; // email sent from
        _subject = ""; // email subject
        _body = "test email message sended!!"; // email body

        _debuggable = false; // debug mode on or off - default off
        _auth = true; // smtp authentication - default on

        _multipart = new MimeMultipart();

        // There is something wrong with MailCap, javamail can not find a handler for the multipart/mixed part, so this bit needs to be added.
        MailcapCommandMap mc = (MailcapCommandMap) CommandMap.getDefaultCommandMap();
        mc.addMailcap("text/html;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html");
        mc.addMailcap("text/xml;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_xml");
        mc.addMailcap("text/plain;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain");
        mc.addMailcap("multipart/*;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed");
        mc.addMailcap("message/rfc822;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.message_rfc822");
        CommandMap.setDefaultCommandMap(mc);
      }

      public GMailSender(String user, String pass) {
        this();

        _user = user;
        _pass = pass;
      }

      public boolean send() throws Exception {
        Properties props = _setProperties();

        if(!_user.equals("") && !_pass.equals("") && _to.length > 0 && !_from.equals("") && !_subject.equals("") && !_body.equals("")) {
          Session session = Session.getInstance(props, this);

          MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);

          msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(_from));

          InternetAddress[] addressTo = new InternetAddress[_to.length];
          for (int i = 0; i < _to.length; i++) {
            addressTo[i] = new InternetAddress(_to[i]);
          }
            msg.setRecipients(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, addressTo);

          msg.setSubject(_subject);
          msg.setSentDate(new Date());

          // setup message body
          BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
          messageBodyPart.setText(_body);
          _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

          // Put parts in message
          msg.setContent(_multipart);

          // send email
          Transport.send(msg);

          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      }

      public void addAttachment(String filename) throws Exception {
        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
        messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
        messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename);

        _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
      }

      @Override
      public javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return  new javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication(_user,_pass);
      }

      private Properties _setProperties() {
        Properties props = new Properties();

        props.put("mail.smtp.host", _host);

        if(_debuggable) {
          props.put("mail.debug", "true");
        }

        if(_auth) {
          props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        }

        props.put("mail.smtp.port", _port);
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", _sport);
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");

        return props;
      }

      // the getters and setters
      public String getBody() {
        return _body;
      }

      public void setBody(String _body) {
        this._body = _body;
      }

    public String[] get_to() {
        return _to;
    }

    public void set_to(String[] _to) {
        this._to = _to;
    }

    public String get_from() {
        return _from;
    }

    public void set_from(String _from) {
        this._from = _from;
    }

    public String get_subject() {
        return _subject;
    }

    public void set_subject(String _subject) {
        this._subject = _subject;
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

NetworkOnMainThreadException: The exception that is thrown when an application attempts to perform a networking operation on its main thread.

Simply saying the tutorial you have followed is quite dated [appears to be from 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a?lq=1). Either find a tutorial which uses async for email sending or modify the code yourself so that it uses async. Async has been introduced quite some time ago and as a result everything dealing with network has to be implemented using it.

[here is link that illustrates how to use asynctask](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2009/05/painless-threading.html)

[NetworkOnMainThreadException Reference Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9413625/android-android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

[Possible Answer Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14374578/using-asynctask-to-send-android-email)
[Sending Email Tutorial August 2013](http://javatechig.com/android/how-to-send-email-in-android)