# Sending a mail using AsyncTask. Got no error, but got no email too

Tags: android, email, gmail, gmail-api

I'm using javax.mail.Authenticator to send an Email but I'm got nothing. When I'm try to less secure my gmail I'm still not get an email. Don't know what I;m did wrong, but there are no error in my code.

I'm just remind something. Some time this code got an broken pipe error. But it very rarely.

This is my MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.yggdrasil.sendmail;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Button send;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);


        send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);
        send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final GMailSender sender = new GMailSender("fxxxxxxxx@gmail.com",
                        "xxxxxxxxx");
                new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
                    @Override public Void doInBackground(Void... arg) {
                        try {
                            sender.sendMail("This is Subject",
                                    "This is Body",
                                    "aaaaaaaaa",
                                    "xxxxxxxxx@gmail.com");
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.e("SendMail", e.getMessage(), e);
                            }
                        return null;
                    }
                    @Override

                    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

                        super.onPostExecute(result);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Email send", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                }.execute();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "After Execute", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: did you add valid email addresses in sendMail???

Comment: In your doInBackground method remove your return statement

Comment: Email is correct. And when I'm remove return statement,  Code error.

Comment: You may want to check the sample code in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14374639/5832311) which is referred in this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). You need to pass your `GMailSender` object in to an `AsyncTask`, and call `GMailSender#sendMail` during `doInBackground`.