# WebView Twitter login window on UI thread

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I'm attempting to allow a user to login via a `WebView` within a `DialogPreference` my application and this work fine, but I seem to be stuck on how to do this properly.

If I do this as next, I get an error

**Error**

```
Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
 E/AndroidRuntime(732):  at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
```

**Code**

```
@Override
protected void onBindDialogView(View v) {
    super.onBindDialogView(v);

    this.webViewOauth = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.web_oauth);     
    try {
        String authURL = this.backend.getRequestToken().getAuthenticationURL();
        webViewOauth.loadUrl(authURL);
    }
    catch (TwitterException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}
```

I can fix this by changing the `ThreadPolicy`, but as far as I can tell, there is a reason for this restriction

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
}
```

So, I switched this to an `AsyncTask` and I get a warning

**Warning**

> java.lang.Throwable: Warning: A WebView method was called on thread
>   'AsyncTask #4'. All WebView methods must be called on the UI thread.
>   Future versions of WebView may not support use on other threads.

**Code**

```
@Override
protected void onBindDialogView(View v) {
    super.onBindDialogView(v);

    MyLoginTask login = new MyLoginTask(this, v, this.backend);
    login.execute();
}
```

Both methods work, but is there a specific way to do this properly? The `ThreadPolicy` seems to be a hack and could cause it to block the UI thread, but I'n not sure if it actually will, while the `AsyncTask` method clearly is incorrect too based on the warning.

Is this an appropriate time to set the `ThreadPolicy` since it actually is running a UI element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, using the ScrictMode Policy *is* a hack, and a terrible one as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9413625/android-android-os-networkonmainthreadexception?lq=1)

You have two ways to solve this:

1- Return the `authURL` from the onPostExecute() method of your MyLoginTask. Simply define a setter in the object that calls the MyLoginTask, and have onPostExecute() assign the result to it.

2- Pass a reference to your webview to the MyLoginTask, and have it load the url in the onPostExecute(). Because onPostExecute() will [always run in the UI thread](http://android-developers.blogspot.ca/2009/05/painless-threading.html), you will get rid of the warning.

In any case, do check out this post by the Android developers about 'Painless Threading'; you will certainly find it helpful: http://android-developers.blogspot.ca/2009/05/painless-threading.html

Comment: Worked perfectly. For others reading this, it was the `getRequestToken().getAuthenticationURL()` that was loading data on the UI thread and the `WebView` isn't the issue.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow btw.