# WebView Twitter OAuth Callback Not Working

Tags: android, multithreading, twitter, oauth, webview

I've been using following a tutorial to make a basic Twitter client, and all I'm trying to do is get the OAuth to work. It takes me to the consent page, but after I click "accept", it doesn't redirect me back to my app. Here's my code:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {

                            requestToken = twitter
                                    .getOAuthRequestToken(TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL);
                            Test.this.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
                                    .parse(requestToken.getAuthenticationURL())));

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
                thread.start();
```

I tried changing the value of TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL, but that didn't help. I followed a suggestion to make a WebView instead of launching the browser, but that didn't work either, since I got an error saying that "All WebView methods must be called on the same thread."

I tried calling the method in the UI thread, like this:

```
final WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv);

            mAppActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {                        
                        requestToken = twitter
                                .getOAuthRequestToken(TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL);
                        wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

                            @Override
                            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                                wv.loadUrl(requestToken.getAuthorizationURL());
                                return true;
                            }
                        });                         
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
```

But this caused a NetworkOnMainThreadException. I also tried implementing an Async task, as shown below, but absolutely nothing happened when I clicked the button which called the method of which this is a snippet, not even any exceptions:

```
private class LoadURLAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override 
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

            WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv);
            wv.loadUrl(urls[0]);

            return null;
        }
    }

try {
                        // get the access token
                        mAppActivity.this.accessToken = 
                                twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(
                                requestToken, verifier);    
                        LoadURLAsync task = new LoadURLAsync();
                        task.execute(new String[] {requestToken.getAuthorizationURL()});
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

I've looked at the following answers, but they I still haven't been able to figure out how to get back to the app from the browser, or a way to get the WebView to work. If anyone has a solution to either of these problems, that would be great, thanks!

[WebView Twitter login window on UI thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16888079/webview-twitter-login-window-on-ui-thread)
[How to fix android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)
[OAuth + Twitter on Android: Callback fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199357/oauth-twitter-on-android-callback-fails)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the URL has to be exactly the same as the android:host and android:scheme parameters in the manifest, combined together. For example:

```
<data
        android:host="x-oauthflow-twitter"
        android:scheme="callback" />

static final String TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL = "callback://x-oauthflow-twitter";
```