# Unfortunately, <app name> has stopped - IllegalStateException:

Tags: java, android, illegalstateexception

I have a problem with an app that I am writing which works on the Samsung S5300 (Android OS 2.3.3) but not on my tablet (Prestigio Multipad 2 Ultra Duo 8.0 3G). It is running (Android OS 4.1)

The app gets some info, like a timestamp and ADC values from a IOIO Board, and Posts it to a server. This works great with the samsung phone. With the tablet it bombs out on the sending of data part.

Here is my code snippet that bombs out:

```
        public void postData() 
    {
        String urlS = "https://posttestserver.com/post.php?dump&html&dir=oan";
        //String urlS =  "https://placidblue.no-ip.biz/cgi-bin/data_input.py";
        //String urlS =  "http://placidblue.no-ip.biz/cgi-bin/data_input.py";

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(); // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(urlS);

        try {
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("LAT", TransferLat));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("LON", TransferLon));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("TIM", TransferTim));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("POL", TransferPol));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("CON", TransferCon));
            try {
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                Log.d("General","UnsupportedEncodingException.xxx");
                e.printStackTrace();// writing error to Log
            }

            Log.d("General Log","Sending_data.xxx");
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); // Execute HTTP Post Request
            Log.d("HttpResponse:", response.toString()+"xxx"); // writing response to log
            Log.d("General","Data_send_complete.xxx");

        }catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Log.d("General","Illegal_State1.xxx");
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("General","Illegal_State2.xxx");
        }
        catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // writing error to Log
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }//end postData
```

My logcat error that I get is as follow:

```
08-13 19:02:50.797: D/General Log(6672): Sending_data.xxx
08-13 19:02:50.816: D/AndroidRuntime(6672): Shutting down VM
08-13 19:02:50.816: W/dalvikvm(6672): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40dce908)
08-13 19:02:50.824: E/AndroidRuntime(6672): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-13 19:02:50.824: E/AndroidRuntime(6672): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
08-13 19:02:50.824: E/AndroidRuntime(6672):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3598)
08-13 19:02:50.824: E/AndroidRuntime(6672):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4091)
08-13 19:02:50.824: E/AndroidRuntime(6672):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17072)
08-13 19:02:50.824: E/AndroidRuntime(6672):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
08-13 19:02:50.824: E/AndroidRuntime(6672):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-13 19:02:50.824: E/AndroidRuntime(6672):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
08-13 19:02:50.824: E/AndroidRuntime(6672):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4987)
08-13 19:02:50.824: E/AndroidRuntime(6672):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-13 19:02:50.824: E/AndroidRuntime(6672):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-13 19:02:50.824: E/AndroidRuntime(6672):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
08-13 19:02:50.824: E/AndroidRuntime(6672):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
08-13 19:02:50.824: E/AndroidRuntime(6672):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-13 19:02:50.824: E/AndroidRuntime(6672): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
08-13 19:02:50.824: E/AndroidRuntime(6672):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-13 19:02:50.824: E/AndroidRuntime(6672):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-13 19:02:50.824: E/AndroidRuntime(6672):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3593)
08-13 19:02:50.824: E/AndroidRuntime(6672):     ... 11 more
08-13 19:02:50.824: E/AndroidRuntime(6672): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
08-13 19:02:50.824: E/AndroidRuntime(6672):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1125)
08-13 19:02:50.824: E/AndroidRuntime(6672):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
08-13 19:02:50.824: E/AndroidRuntime(6672):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
08-13 19:02:50.824: E/AndroidRuntime(6672):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
08-13 19:02:50.824: E/AndroidRuntime(6672):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
08-13 19:02:50.824: E/AndroidRuntime(6672):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
08-13 19:02:50.824: E/AndroidRuntime(6672):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
08-13 19:02:50.824: E/AndroidRuntime(6672):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:365)
08-13 19:02:50.824: E/AndroidRuntime(6672):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
08-13 19:02:50.824: E/AndroidRuntime(6672):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
08-13 19:02:50.824: E/AndroidRuntime(6672):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
08-13 19:02:50.824: E/AndroidRuntime(6672):     at com.example.airsensor1.MainActivity.postData(MainActivity.java:194)
08-13 19:02:50.824: E/AndroidRuntime(6672):     at com.example.airsensor1.MainActivity.sendData(MainActivity.java:158)
08-13 19:02:50.824: E/AndroidRuntime(6672):     ... 14 more
```

I beleive that it might even be some security problem with permissions on the new OS?
I have set the appropriate internet permisions in the manifest.

Any advice would be appreciated.
Regards

Comment: Google for `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

Comment: **Always** check for the `Caused by` part (and line number). No need to guess. Computers are smart.

Comment: please see this answer: 
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9413625/android-android-os-networkonmainthreadexception

Comment: @Keyser Particularly OP should Google (or Bing) the last `caused by` part. In this case "android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException" and if that doesn't help, try the next line "android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to access the internet while on the main UI thread. Any type of network access can block, which will make your UI unresponsive. Android now enforces a policy that network operations not be run on the main UI thread.

Use AsyncTask, IntentService, Java threading constructs, or some other way to remove that work from the main thread.