# android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException sending an email from Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, smtpclient, networkonmainthread

I have written an application which sends email from an Android device, but I get the following exception when I try to send an email:

`android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`

Why is this occurring and how can I fix it?

Comment: It's because you're doing network operations on the UI thread.

Comment: Do all network related operations on background thread.

Answer (score 8):

Which SDK version? If 14+ see [this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html).

The solution is

**JUST FOR DEBUG**

Add these rows

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

**Real Case**

Put the code on an AsyncTask:

```
private class Connection extends AsyncTask {
    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... arg0) {

        connect();
        return null;
    }
}
```

And then call:

```
new Connection().execute("");
```

Comment: ok thanks solved using the StrictMode

Comment: Do Not use StrictMode in production Mode, use the AsyncTask

Comment: @user2693552 just to add what venergiac is saying - this is _not_ a solution to your issue, it's a workaround to be used so you can test **other parts** of your app are working, and you must move this network operation to another thread later. As your application seems to require this network operation as a critical component, I'd suggest sorting it out now, and not bothering with setting this thread policy.

Comment: The correct mode to call is Connection().execute("");

Answer (score 2):

This exception means that you are trying to do a *network* related operation on the main UI thread. You need to do either in a separate thread or in AsyncTask.

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html) says that:

> The exception that is thrown when an application attempts to perform a
> networking operation on its main thread. This is only thrown for applications
> targeting the [Honeycomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history#Android_3.0_Honeycomb_.28API_level_11.29) SDK or higher. Applications targeting earlier SDK
> versions are allowed to do networking on their main event loop threads, but it's
> heavily discouraged.

See *[How can I fix 'android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)* and *[Android - android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9413625/android-android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)* for more.

Something like:

```
class RetreiveFeedTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {
        // Execute the network related option here
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void param) {

        // TODO: do something with the feed
    }
}
```

This is how to execute the task:

```
new RetreiveFeedTask().execute(urlToRssFeed);
```

Comment: Yes I know but how to solve?

Comment: As I said put you code inside AsyncTask or start a new thread. You can go to those links that I mentioned for more.