# httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

Tags: android

My android app keeps on crashing. 
I'm trying to connect to a webservice via post call.
But my app keeps on crashing every time it tries to call the webservice.

```
 import android.app.Activity;

    import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
    import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
    import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
    import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

    import java.io.IOException;
    public class PostActivity extends Activity {

        //static String response = null;

        public void loadPost() throws IOException {
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
            HttpResponse httpResponse = null;

            String blogFeedUrl = "http://localhost/medapp/public/mobile/post";

            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(blogFeedUrl);
            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);  // <-- this is where the application crashes

        }

    }
```

Comment: _"crashing"_ is not a valid description of your problem. Read up on basic debugging. Tips: Read the logcat, learn how to interpret a stack trace. Also, going through the tutorials on the dev site is useful in the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code you have posted and related imports in the same, depending on the O.S(Esp Honeycomb and onwards), your application would crash due to the `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. You are attempting the network operation on the main thread, not in a background thread or [Asyctask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

In your logcat(if you post that it'l help), `NetworkOnMainThreadException` will be thrown:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(673): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
    ComponentInfo{com.example/com.example.ExampleActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

The explanation as to why this occurs is well documented on the [Android developer's site](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html):

> A `NetworkOnMainThreadException` is thrown when an application
>   attempts to perform a networking operation on its main thread. This is
>   only thrown for applications targeting the Honeycomb SDK or higher.
>   Applications targeting earlier SDK versions are allowed to do
>   networking on their main event loop threads, but it's heavily
>   discouraged.

Go through:

[Why the app would crash or work depending on O.S.](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/06/app-force-close-honeycomb-ics.html)

[Try AsyncTask to avoid NetworkOnMainThread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

Why should you not use the Strict Mode alternative as your solution and only to debug(i'd suggest avoid that also actually, you know what is the problem now):
[Critical to fix it, not by setting Thread policies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18297485/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception-sending-an-email-from-android/18297516#18297516)