# Can I publish my app with StrictMode?

Tags: android

Can I publish my app in market with code like this

```
try
      {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().detectNetwork().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy( policy );

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
....        
  }
catch( Throwable ignore )
      {
      .....
      }
```

I read that strict mode just for debug regime and when I publish app I have to delete it.

Comment: Yes, but also read [Why is it not advisable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18297485/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception-sending-an-email-from-android/18297516#18297516)

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can, but it's not recommended since `StrictMode.ThreadPolicy` is designed to help you find threading issue at the time of development, and there's no sense to have it in production. Furthermore, if you're using `penaltyDeath()`, you don't want the app to crash while in production.