# I am parsing links and assign them to buttons in android 4.3 with json,why its not showing the pages when I click them on the app?

Tags: android, json, eclipse, android-4.4-kitkat, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I am using asynctask, json, eclipse juno.
I am parsing some tags from a json file,im getting them perfectly,in some textviews, and I am trying to parse some links as data to assign them to buttons on my project. im getting the buttons working on my project from Android 2.1 to Android 4.1.2,.but in Android 4.2-4.4 the buttons aren't working,it doesn't crash,and I am not getting an error,it just does like its going to open the browser and goes back to the layout where the buttons are at.

Any idea if the way that I am trying to do has change in android 4.2?

SingleContactActivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class SingleContactActivity  extends Activity {

// JSON node keys
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "email";
private static final String TAG_PHONE_MOBILE = "mobile";
private static final String TAG_ADDRESS = "address";
private static final String TAG_GENDER = "gender";
static final String KEY_AUDIO= "audio";
static final String KEY_VIDEO = "video";
static final String KEY_WEB = "web";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_single_contact);

    // getting intent data
    Intent in = getIntent();

    // Get JSON values from previous intent
    String name = in.getStringExtra(TAG_NAME);
    String email = in.getStringExtra(TAG_EMAIL);
    String mobile = in.getStringExtra(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE);
    String address = in.getStringExtra(TAG_ADDRESS);
    String gender = in.getStringExtra(TAG_GENDER);
    final String uriUrl = in.getStringExtra(KEY_AUDIO);
    final String uriUrl2 = in.getStringExtra(KEY_VIDEO);
    final String uriUrl3 = in.getStringExtra(KEY_WEB);

    // Displaying all values on the screen
    TextView lblName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name_label);
    TextView lblEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.email_label);
    TextView lblMobile = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mobile_label);
    TextView lblAddress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.address_label);
    TextView lblGender = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gender_label);

    lblName.setText(name);
    lblEmail.setText(email);
    lblMobile.setText(mobile);
    lblAddress.setText(address);
    lblGender.setText(gender);

    Button btnaudio = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonA);
    btnaudio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.setData(Uri.parse(uriUrl));
            startActivity(i);


        }
    });

    Button btnvideo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonV);
    btnvideo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.setData(Uri.parse(uriUrl2));
            startActivity(i);


        }
    });

    Button btnweb = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonW);
    btnweb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.setData(Uri.parse(uriUrl3));
            startActivity(i);


        }
    });   

}
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
import net.umalc.R;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
```

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

```
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// URL to get contacts JSON
private static String url = "http://www.revgrades.com/contacts";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_CONTACTS = "contacts";
private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "email";
private static final String TAG_ADDRESS = "address";
private static final String TAG_GENDER = "gender";
private static final String TAG_AUDIO = "audio";
private static final String TAG_VIDEO = "video";
private static final String TAG_WEB = "web";
private static final String TAG_PHONE = "phone";
private static final String TAG_PHONE_MOBILE = "mobile";
private static final String TAG_PHONE_HOME = "home";
private static final String TAG_PHONE_OFFICE = "office";

// contacts JSONArray
JSONArray contacts = null;

// Hashmap for ListView
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    ListView lv = getListView();

    // Listview on item click listener
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name))
                    .getText().toString();
            String email = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.email))
                    .getText().toString();
            String mobile = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mobile))
                    .getText().toString();
            String address = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.address))
                    .getText().toString();
            String gender =((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.gender))
                    .getText().toString();
            String audio =((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.audio))
                    .getText().toString();
            String video =((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.video))
                    .getText().toString();
            String web =((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.web))
                    .getText().toString();
            // Starting single contact activity
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    SingleContactActivity.class);
            in.putExtra(TAG_NAME, name);
            in.putExtra(TAG_EMAIL, email);
            in.putExtra(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE, mobile);
            in.putExtra(TAG_ADDRESS, address);
            in.putExtra(TAG_GENDER, gender);
            in.putExtra(TAG_AUDIO, audio);
            in.putExtra(TAG_VIDEO, video);
            in.putExtra(TAG_WEB, web);


            startActivity(in);

        }
    });

    // Calling async task to get json
    new GetContacts().execute();
}

private Dialog getSupportActionBar() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

/**
 * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
 * */
private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Showing progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // Creating service handler class instance
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                // Getting JSON Array node
                contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTS);

                // looping through All Contacts
                for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                    String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    String email = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
                    String address = c.getString(TAG_ADDRESS);
                    String gender = c.getString(TAG_GENDER);
                    String audio = c.getString(TAG_AUDIO);
                    String video = c.getString(TAG_VIDEO);
                    String web = c.getString(TAG_WEB);

                    // Phone node is JSON Object
                    JSONObject phone = c.getJSONObject(TAG_PHONE);
                    String mobile = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE);
                    String home = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_HOME);
                    String office = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_OFFICE);

                    // tmp hashmap for single contact
                    HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    contact.put(TAG_ID, id);
                    contact.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                    contact.put(TAG_EMAIL, email);
                    contact.put(TAG_ADDRESS, address);
                    contact.put(TAG_GENDER, gender);
                    contact.put(TAG_AUDIO, audio);
                    contact.put(TAG_VIDEO, video);
                    contact.put(TAG_WEB, web);


                    // adding contact to contact list
                    contactList.add(contact);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
        /**
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * */
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                MainActivity.this, contactList,
                R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_NAME, TAG_EMAIL,
                        TAG_ADDRESS, TAG_GENDER, TAG_AUDIO, TAG_VIDEO, TAG_WEB }, new int[] { R.id.name,
                        R.id.email, R.id.address, R.id.gender, R.id.audio, R.id.video, R.id.web  });

        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

}

}
```

This is what logcat says when im trying to click the buttons:

```
   02-11 06:04:14.002: I/ActivityManager(298): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=http://www.conciencia.net/mensajes/2014/feb/2014feb01.mp3 cmp=com.android.browser/.BrowserActivity} from pid 1225
    02-11 06:04:14.012: W/WindowManager(298): Failure taking screenshot for (328x546) to layer 21025
    02-11 06:04:14.303: D/WebViewTimersControl(1257): onBrowserActivityResume
    02-11 06:04:14.303: D/WebViewTimersControl(1257): Resuming webview timers, view=com.android.browser.BrowserWebView{410c0550 VFEDHVCL .F....I. 0,0-0,0}
    02-11 06:04:14.722: E/SurfaceFlinger(36): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
    02-11 06:04:14.772: I/Choreographer(1257): Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    02-11 06:04:15.483: I/ActivityManager(298): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=http://www.conciencia.net/mensajes/2014/feb/2014feb01.mp3 typ=audio/mpeg cmp=com.android.music/.AudioPreview} from pid 1257
    02-11 06:04:15.483: W/WindowManager(298): Failure taking screenshot for (328x546) to layer 22025
    02-11 06:04:15.782: D/webviewglue(1257): nativeDestroy view: 0x2a31d728
    02-11 06:04:16.012: W/ActivityManager(298): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{41359340 u0 com.android.browser/.BrowserActivity}
    02-11 06:04:16.502: I/ActivityManager(298): moveTaskToBack: 7
    02-11 06:04:16.553: I/Choreographer(1257): Skipped 139 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    02-11 06:04:16.702: D/WebViewTimersControl(1257): onBrowserActivityPause
    02-11 06:04:16.702: D/WebViewTimersControl(1257): Pausing webview timers, view=com.android.browser.BrowserWebView{40d12fb0 VFEDHVCL ......ID 0,0-768,1134}
02-11 06:04:17.012: D/dalvikvm(532): GC_CONCURRENT freed 166K, 10% free 2707K/2992K, paused 7ms+21ms, total 136ms
    02-11 06:04:17.042: W/ActivityManager(298): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{40ef81d8 u0 com.android.music/.AudioPreview}
    02-11 06:04:17.162: E/SurfaceFlinger(36): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
    02-11 06:04:17.333: D/MediaPlayer(532): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
    02-11 06:04:17.373: I/AwesomePlayer(39): setDataSource_l(URL suppressed)
    02-11 06:04:17.393: E/Trace(39): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
    02-11 06:04:17.962: I/qtaguid(39): Tagging socket 27 with tag 3f500000000(1013) for uid 10032 failed errno=-2
    02-11 06:04:18.333: E/WVMExtractor(39): Failed to open libwvm.so
    02-11 06:04:18.602: I/Choreographer(1257): Skipped 39 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    02-11 06:04:20.043: I/Choreographer(532): Skipped 67 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    02-11 06:04:20.103: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(1257): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
    02-11 06:04:20.392: D/AudioSink(39): bufferCount (4) is too small and increased to 12
    02-11 06:04:20.523: I/AudioService(298):  AudioFocus  requestAudioFocus() from android.media.AudioManager@40cf0058com.android.music.AudioPreview$2@40d063f8
    02-11 06:04:22.782: I/NuCachedSource2(39): ERROR_END_OF_STREAM
    02-11 06:04:31.413: D/ExchangeService(701): Received deviceId from Email app: null
    02-11 06:04:31.413: D/ExchangeService(701): !!! deviceId unknown; stopping self and retrying
    02-11 06:04:36.443: D/ExchangeService(701): !!! EAS ExchangeService, onStartCommand, startingUp = false, running = false
    02-11 06:04:36.443: W/ActivityManager(298): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.android.email.ACCOUNT_INTENT } U=0: not found
    02-11 06:04:36.452: D/ExchangeService(701): !!! Email application not found; stopping self
    02-11 06:04:36.472: W/ActivityManager(298): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.android.email.ACCOUNT_INTENT } U=0: not found
    02-11 06:04:36.494: E/ActivityThread(701): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d66c68 that was originally bound here
    02-11 06:04:36.494: E/ActivityThread(701): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d66c68 that was originally bound here
    02-11 06:04:36.494: E/ActivityThread(701):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
    02-11 06:04:36.494: E/ActivityThread(701):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
    02-11 06:04:36.494: E/ActivityThread(701):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
    02-11 06:04:36.494: E/ActivityThread(701):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
    02-11 06:04:36.494: E/ActivityThread(701):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
    02-11 06:04:36.494: E/ActivityThread(701):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
    02-11 06:04:36.494: E/ActivityThread(701):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
    02-11 06:04:36.494: E/ActivityThread(701):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
    02-11 06:04:36.494: E/ActivityThread(701):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
    02-11 06:04:36.494: E/ActivityThread(701):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
    02-11 06:04:36.494: E/ActivityThread(701):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
    02-11 06:04:36.494: E/ActivityThread(701):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
    02-11 06:04:36.494: E/ActivityThread(701):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
    02-11 06:04:36.494: E/ActivityThread(701):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
    02-11 06:04:36.494: E/ActivityThread(701):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
    02-11 06:04:36.494: E/ActivityThread(701):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
    02-11 06:04:36.522: E/StrictMode(701): null
    02-11 06:04:36.522: E/StrictMode(701): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d66c68 that was originally bound here
    02-11 06:04:36.522: E/StrictMode(701):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
    02-11 06:04:36.522: E/StrictMode(701):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
    02-11 06:04:36.522: E/StrictMode(701):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
    02-11 06:04:36.522: E/StrictMode(701):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
    02-11 06:04:36.522: E/StrictMode(701):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
    02-11 06:04:36.522: E/StrictMode(701):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
    02-11 06:04:36.522: E/StrictMode(701):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
    02-11 06:04:36.522: E/StrictMode(701):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
    02-11 06:04:36.522: E/StrictMode(701):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
    02-11 06:04:36.522: E/StrictMode(701):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
    02-11 06:04:36.522: E/StrictMode(701):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
    02-11 06:04:36.522: E/StrictMode(701):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
    02-11 06:04:36.522: E/StrictMode(701):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
    02-11 06:04:36.522: E/StrictMode(701):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
    02-11 06:04:36.522: E/StrictMode(701):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
    02-11 06:04:36.522: E/StrictMode(701):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
    02-11 06:04:36.532: W/ActivityManager(298): Unbind failed: could not find connection for android.os.BinderProxy@40faf1f8
    02-11 06:04:36.563: E/ActivityThread(701): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d672d8 that was originally bound here
    02-11 06:04:36.563: E/ActivityThread(701): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d672d8 that was originally bound here
    02-11 06:04:36.563: E/ActivityThread(701):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
    02-11 06:04:36.563: E/ActivityThread(701):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
    02-11 06:04:36.563: E/ActivityThread(701):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
    02-11 06:04:36.563: E/ActivityThread(701):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
    02-11 06:04:36.563: E/ActivityThread(701):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
    02-11 06:04:36.563: E/ActivityThread(701):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
    02-11 06:04:36.563: E/ActivityThread(701):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
    02-11 06:04:36.563: E/ActivityThread(701):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
    02-11 06:04:36.563: E/ActivityThread(701):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
    02-11 06:04:36.563: E/ActivityThread(701):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
    02-11 06:04:36.563: E/ActivityThread(701):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
    02-11 06:04:36.563: E/ActivityThread(701):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
    02-11 06:04:36.563: E/ActivityThread(701):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
    02-11 06:04:36.563: E/ActivityThread(701):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
    02-11 06:04:36.563: E/ActivityThread(701):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
    02-11 06:04:36.563: E/ActivityThread(701):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
    02-11 06:04:36.563: E/ActivityThread(701):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
    02-11 06:04:36.582: D/dalvikvm(701): GC_CONCURRENT freed 465K, 20% free 2510K/3104K, paused 7ms+12ms, total 82ms
    02-11 06:04:36.602: E/StrictMode(701): null
    02-11 06:04:36.602: E/StrictMode(701): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d672d8 that was originally bound here
    02-11 06:04:36.602: E/StrictMode(701):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
    02-11 06:04:36.602: E/StrictMode(701):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
    02-11 06:04:36.602: E/StrictMode(701):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
    02-11 06:04:36.602: E/StrictMode(701):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
    02-11 06:04:36.602: E/StrictMode(701):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
    02-11 06:04:36.602: E/StrictMode(701):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
    02-11 06:04:36.602: E/StrictMode(701):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
    02-11 06:04:36.602: E/StrictMode(701):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
    02-11 06:04:36.602: E/StrictMode(701):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
    02-11 06:04:36.602: E/StrictMode(701):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
    02-11 06:04:36.602: E/StrictMode(701):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
    02-11 06:04:36.602: E/StrictMode(701):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
    02-11 06:04:36.602: E/StrictMode(701):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
    02-11 06:04:36.602: E/StrictMode(701):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
    02-11 06:04:36.602: E/StrictMode(701):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
    02-11 06:04:36.602: E/StrictMode(701):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
    02-11 06:04:36.602: E/StrictMode(701):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
    02-11 06:04:36.602: W/ActivityManager(298): Unbind failed: could not find connection for android.os.BinderProxy@40e6ab38
```

Comment: Do you have any code we could see?

Comment: ok,ill edit my question,ill put the code there

Answer (score 0):

You must be getting the NetworkOnMainThreadException , check your logcat. Also pls post it. Will edit/remove my answer if its not that.

It'l be good to know why it occurs and how can you use async task:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html
http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html

[How to fix android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)
[Android - android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9413625/android-android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

Comment: im editing the original post,there You can see how im using asynctask.

Comment: pls post your logcat--for when you click the button

Comment: im updating the post with feedback from the logcat

Comment: yeah user2450263 it looks like thats going to be the problem,I tried 5 times,I've clicked 5 times the buttons and thats the report from logcat !

Comment: that log didn't help, "Log.i("onClick","-----------");" or something to indicate the click

Comment: Yes Buddy !,thanks for the edit !,i have a little reputation points,and the code was way so long ,to be manually edited!

Comment: No problem, what is your targetSdkVersion?

Comment: <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="5"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />