# Finding exception while sending data from android app to server

Tags: android, networkonmainthread

I am trying to send data from Android app to server .... but on click to save button causes `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` and app stops.
Please can anyone help?

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://farahkhan.byethost15.com/try.php");
try {

    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
       nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "01"));
       nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", signupemailString));

       httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

       httpclient.execute(httppost);

       signupemail.setText(""); //reset the message text field
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Sent",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with this:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                     HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://farahkhan.byethost15.com/try.php");
                try {

                    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                       nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "01"));
                       nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", signupemailString));

                       httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                       httpclient.execute(httppost);
                       runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                             signupemail.setText(""); //reset the message text field
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Sent",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    });

                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

                }
            }).start();
```

and also add a permission in your manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: @user3561798 you should use `AsyncTask`.

Comment: @user3561798 : but AsyncTask is more reliable and cleaner way to do such works

Comment: @Arash : I also used that method ... but I could not receive or handle it properly .... then I start working like this ....

Answer (score 0):

Add internet permission to your manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

After that Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9413625/android-android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

Comment: it doesn't related to this issue!

Comment: I have already add permission in manifest..