# Excute URL get, Error when executing urlget

Tags: android, android-networking

I want to excute a simple url get, I used the code inside this link
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html

I want to run this code inside a click event:

```java
URL url = new URL("http://www.android.com/");
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
try {
    InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
    readStream(in);}
finally {
    urlConnection.disconnect();
}
```

When I run the app I am getting this long error:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.example.soma.smsserver1, PID: 20664
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
> at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:289)
> at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
> at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
> Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:284)
> at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
> at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
> Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
> at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1273)
> at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:431)
> at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
> at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
> at com.android.okhttp.internal.Network$1.resolveInetAddresses(Network.java:29)
> at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:188)
> at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:157)
> at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:100)
> at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.createNextConnection(HttpEngine.java:357)
> at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:340)
> at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:330)
> at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:248)
> at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:433)
> at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:384)
> at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:231)
> at com.example.soma.smsserver1.MainActivity$override.clickMe(MainActivity.java:28)
> at com.example.soma.smsserver1.MainActivity$override.access$dispatch(MainActivity.java)
> at com.example.soma.smsserver1.MainActivity.clickMe(MainActivity.java:0)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
> at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:284) 
> at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
> at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Comment: Check out the answers on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9413625/android-android-os-networkonmainthreadexception) thread. You're probably performing the request on the main (UI) thread. You should use AsyncTask or the Volley library to perform the http request in the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1273)

you cannot process networking on the main thread, this is a security restriction on Android, try wrapping your call in AsyncTask a background service, or thread.

Please read documentation regarding [Processes and Threads](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html)

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a network Request on the MainThread, which is prohibited because it would block the UI during this call.
You should use an other `Thread` to do this call, you have different options : `Thread`, `AsyncTask`, etc ...

Some examples here :
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html

Answer (score 0):

you are handling network on Main Thread which will make your app hang so, you need to handle long running task on background service like AsyncTask 
check this link https://www.upwork.com/hiring/mobile/why-you-should-use-asynctask-in-android-development/