# Calling REST api on android emulator causes app to crash

Tags: android, rest, api, kotlin

I am relatively new to android studio. I am trying to build a very simple app that fetches the price of cryptocurrencies using the Bittrex exchanges api. However every time I try to get the info from the URL, my app crashes. I am using Kotlin by the way. I'm having trouble solving this because I don't know how to run the emulator in debug mode, just the compiler. Here is my code:

```
package com.example.sebastian.cryptoapp

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import java.net.URL
import java.net.MalformedURLException
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

fun search(): String {
    //read in value
    var market = searchBar.getText().toString()
    //output text from URL query
    val result = URL("https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getticker?market=" 
+ market).readText()
    return result
}

fun getPrice(): String {
    //calling search function
    var info = search()
    //split the string into a list
    var list: List<String> = info.split(":", "}")
    //access 7th index of list for last traded price
    return list[6]
}


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

button.setOnClickListener {
    text_output.setText(getPrice())
}
}
}
```

Comment: Learning how to use the debugger is a priority. Then you can check if you're actually getting what you expect back from the api. I'm guessing here, but I think list[6] is out of bounds.

Comment: I tested the code in IntelliJ beforehand and it worked so I know it's not that

Answer (score 2):

This line here:
`val result = URL("https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getticker?market=" + market).readText()` looks like it is being run on the main thread. This will cause the app to crash with a a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

You can read more on this exception [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html).

Also, make sure you have the following in your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Check out these answers for more information on how to run this in the background:

- [How to fix android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/how-to-fix-android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)
- [Android - android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9413625/android-android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

Alternatively in Kotlin you could also [Anko](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2015/05/advanced-features-of-anko/) or [Coroutines](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines.html).

Comment: Thank you very much, this was very helpful.