# Send JsonObject in POST from android to server

Tags: java, android, json, server, httpurlconnection

I want to send this jsonobject `finalObject` to this server address http://www.xxxx.com/app/pruebaurl  I am using this code

```
     try {

                URL url = new URL("http://www.xxxx.com/app/pruebaurl");

                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");
                httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
                httpURLConnection.connect();

                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8");
                outputStreamWriter.write(finalObject.toString());
                outputStreamWriter.flush();
                outputStreamWriter.close();

   BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));

            String line = null;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }

            bufferedReader.close();
            result = sb.toString();

      }catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
      }
```

but when I run the code by debug  I notice that when jumping from line

```
 httpURLConnection.connect();
```

to line

```
OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
```

Generates an error and goes to the exception where it tells me the following

```
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

I'm working on a fragment, what I can do to fix this error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17063831/3395198

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for performing network operations. You cannot perform it on main thread.

Answer (score 0):

In android you are not allowed to do network on your main thread (UI thread).
Please use a different thread as mentioned in: [How to fix android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/how-to-fix-android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

Use AsyncTask or any thread to solve that.